# sql query to split a sentence and search for result on each word

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ebay-api

I have a API response from eBay on a categoryName ie: "E Liquids & E Cig Cartridges" The trouble is, I cant search for "E" would bring back too many results on my own category list, so I would have to scan the sentence for words larger than 3 letters or even 4, I need to search each word then look up my own category list to see which best suits the unknown sentence from the API call and set the category to the best match, I'm not a sql wizard hence my question. I would imagine a create a temporary sql function then loop until a result is found. Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: You can't do this easily in SQL, split the string in PHP.

Comment: Yes, thanks, i'll give it ago, only trouble is f my query returns 6 results, which one then? suppose its user choice more implementation.. thxs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to accomplish this:

```
/*
CREATE TABLE testData(result INT, term CHAR(255));
INSERT INTO testData VALUES
    (1, 'Cig'),
    (2, 'Liquids'),
    (3, 'E');
*/

SET @NGram = 'E Liquids & E Cig Cartridges';

DELIMITER $

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS parseNGram$

CREATE PROCEDURE parseNGram(VNGram TEXT)
BEGIN

    DECLARE VN, VLoopPos, VGramLength INTEGER; 
    DECLARE VGram CHAR(255);

    SET VN = CHAR_LENGTH(VNGram) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(VNGram, ' ', '')) + 1;
    SET VLoopPos = 0;

    searchLoop: WHILE VLoopPos < VN DO

        SET VGramLength = LOCATE(' ', VNGram);
        SET VGram = LEFT(VNGram, VGRamLength);
        SET VNGram = RIGHT(VNGram, CHAR_LENGTH(VNGram) - VGramLength);

        IF CHAR_LENGTH(VGram) > 1 THEN

            # Do someting with the required token, here is an example
            SELECT result FROM testData WHERE term = VGram LIMIT 1;
            LEAVE searchLoop;
        END IF;

    END WHILE;

END$

DELIMITER ;

CALL parseNGram(@NGram);
```

Let me know if I missed anything,

Regards,

James

Comment: would this work in MySQL using php? my current call is using pdo

$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT as id FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name = 'listings'");

Comment: That query is executable but I can't see how that fits with your question. As Barmar points out this problem could probably be more easily handled using PHP however as the question asked for a MySQL solution I gave the answer above. If you require a PHP orientated answer I'd suggest reposting.

Comment: Yes probably over complicated for my needs, i'll see what I can do exploding the sentence and using PHP like you said. Thank you